# How to tell NSTextView which side to extend selection on?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstextview

If I have an `NSTextView` which is in this state:

[image: NSTextView with partial text selected]

How can I tell the textview that if a user presses <kbd>shift+right</kbd>, that rather than extending right towards the 'o', it instead de-selects the 'e'? I though this had to do with the [affinity](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac//documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTextView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSTextView/selectionAffinity), but I have tried setting it to both `NSSelectionAffinityUpstream` and `NSSelectionAffinityDownstream` via the following code:

```
[self setSelectionRange: NSMakeRange(9,6)
               affinity: x
         stillSelecting: NO];
```

But that made no different. Hitting <kbd>shift+right</kbd> still selected the 'o'.

`NSTextView` knows how to do this SOMEHOW, because if you cursor position between 'w' and 'o', then hit <kbd>shift+left</kbd> until it matches the screenshot, then hit <kbd>shift+right</kbd>, it matches the behaviour I mentioned.

I'm ok to override the <kbd>shift+arrow</kbd> code and roll my own, but I would rather allow `NSTextView` to do its own thing. Anyone know if I am missing anything?

Comment: You can monitor the key down event and ask your control to what you want to do when user press your desired key.

NSEvent  *localMonitor = [NSEvent addLocalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:NSKeyDownMask handler:^(NSEvent *theEvent) {
  
//check your key here

//if its matches to your key. modify it as dummy event

//ask your text view to perform

      
  }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do, since this is the default text movement/selection modification behavior. Are you trying to override this to always do this one thing or are you trying to add another keyboard shortcut that overrides this behavior? In either case, some background:

Selection affinity doesn't quite work the way it sounds (this is a surprise to me after researching it just now). In fact there seems to be a disconnect between the affinity and the inherited `NSResponder` actions corresponding to movement and selection modification. I'll get to that in a moment.

What you want to look at are the responder actions like `-moveBackwardAndModifySelection:`, `-moveWordBackwardAndModifySelection:`, and so on. Per the documentation, the first call to such selection-modifying movement actions determines the "end" of the selection that will be modified with subsequent calls to modify selection in either direction. This means that if your first action was to select forward (`-moveForwardAndModifySelection:`), the "forward end" (right end in left-to-right languages; left end in right-to-left, automagically) is what will be modified from that point forward, whether you call `-moveForward...` or `-moveBackward...`.

I discovered the disconnect between affinity and `-move...AndModifySelection:` by looking at the [open source Cocoatron version of NSTextView](https://github.com/cjwl/cocotron/blob/master/AppKit/NSTextView.subproj/NSTextView.m). It appears the internal _affinity property isn't consulted in any of the move-and-select methods. It determines whether the selection range change should be "upstream" or "downstream" based on `_selectionOrigin`, a private property that is set when the selection ranges are modified (via the `-setSelectedRange(s)...` method or a mouse down / drag). I think the affinity property is just there for you to consult. Overriding it to always return one value or another doesn't change any behavior, it just misreports to outsiders. The `_selectionOrigin` seems only to be modified via `-setSelectedRanges...` method *if the selection is zero-length* (ie, just cursor placement).

So, with all this in mind, you might have to add one step to your manual selection modification: First set an empty selection with a location where you'd like the selection origin to be (forward end if you want backward affinity; backward end if you want forward affinity), *then* set a non-zero-length selection with the desired affinity.

Roundabout and ridiculous, I know, but I think that's how it has to be, given the CocoaTron source code.

Comment: Thanks @JoshuaNozzie My intent was to customize the word selection (cmd+shift+arrow) which I had working using my own selectionOrigin property, but then if the user used the default shift+arrow (no cmd) I had no way to tell it where I 'left off' so to speak. Your comments will help me a ton!

Comment: There are two private members controlling the same behavioral trait that can get out of sync when selection length is non-zero. I'm calling this a bug: rdar://21422241 :-)

Comment: In your case, then, I'd override -keyDown: and if I detect that combo, note the current selection, apply the zero-length selection, then restore the selection with the desired affinity. I'd then always call super (since you want the default behavior after you assert the affinity/origin, or if any other key combo). That should work around the bug and keep selection origin in proper sync.

Comment: The docs on `selectionAffinity` say "Selection affinity determines whether, for example, the insertion point appears after the last character on a line or before the first character on the following line in cases where text wraps across line boundaries."  So I don't think it was intended to affect which end of a selection range moves.

Comment: @JWWalker ...but it should, I feel. If I specify affinity, the internal state should be updated to reflect that regardless of the length of the selection. Further, if there's a non-zero-length selection, there *is* no cursor shown and the affinity doesn't matter on subsequent non-selection movements (try it - select something and press the right arrow, then again pressing the left arrow - affinity doesn't matter; cursor appears at whatever end you move toward without modifying selection).

Comment: @JWWalker What I mean is, there *is* no "cursor" per se when there's a non-zero selection. A zero-length selection is just a "cursor position" and keyboard or mouse movement with non-zero-length selection(s) causes a zero-length selection. It's just that the cursor is placed at the end of the (now-former) selection(s) determined by the pressed arrow key.